# Python code for sorting and moving files by types

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, shutil

My code is working fine to serve its objective but there is a small bug which I can not over ride. It is about "makedir" command in python code.

I have lots of files in my downloads section. So thought of sorting them as per their files types to organize the folder. The project includes -

1. Creating directories for storing different file types according to
   their types.
2. Identifying and moving files to respective directories according to
   their types.
   I have return a code mentioned below.

```
import os, glob, shutil

os.chdir('/home/something/Downloads')
src_dir = os.path.join('/home/something/Downloads')
try:
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/excel')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/image')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/pdf')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/word')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/python')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/text')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/gimp')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/video')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/presentation')
    os.makedirs('/home/something/Downloads/zip')

except FileExistsError:
    pass

pdfDir = (src_dir + '/pdf')
txtDir = src_dir + '/text'
pyDir = src_dir + '/python'
docDir = src_dir + '/word'
gimpDir = src_dir + '/gimp'
imgDir = src_dir + '/image'
avDir = src_dir + '/video'
pptxDir = src_dir + '/presentation'
zipDir = src_dir + '/zip'
excelDir = src_dir + '/excel'

pdfFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.pdf')
txtFiles= glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.txt')
pyFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.py')
docFiles = (glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.docx') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.docs') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*doc') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.odt') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.DOC'))
gimpFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.svg') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.xcf')
imgFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.img') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.png') + (glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.jpg') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.jpeg')+ glob.glob(src_dir +'/*.JPG'))
avFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.mp4')
pptxFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.pptx')
zipFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.zip')
excelFiles = glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.xlxs') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.xlsx') + glob.glob(src_dir + '/*.ods')

for files in pdfFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, pdfDir)
for files in pyFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, pyDir)
for files in txtFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, txtDir)
for files in gimpFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, gimpDir)
for files in docFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, docDir)
for files in imgFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, imgDir)
for files in avFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, avDir)
for files in pptxFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, pptxDir)
for files in zipFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, zipDir)
for files in excelFiles:
    shutil.copy(files, excelDir)
```

It works very fine and serves the purpose except **one difficulty**. If "makedirs" command encounters with a file name already existing in Directory "Downloads", it pass the command and dose not create new directory. For instance if file name "image" is already existing in the directory "Downloads" then, "makedirs" command fails to create new directory with same name and so the the image files types are not sorted accordingly.

I am not sure how to resolve this bug as there is no "directoryExistsError" as "FileExistsError"!

Kindly guide.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it right, but if a directory exists and it's ok for you, you could pass `exist_ok=True` to `makedirs` so it doesn't raise any exception: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs

Comment: Also you can see in docs that `OSError` exception is raised if a directory exists, NOT `FileExistsError`

Comment: Can't reproduce that problem. A `FileExistsError` is raised for both already existing files and directories with the same name.

Comment: @Winand `OSError` is a superclass of `FileExistsError`. At least in my case a `FileExistsError` is being raised.

Comment: @Winand is I pass `exit_ok=True` to `makedirs` it will probably create new directory even if it exist. I don't want this to happen. But I want the new directory to be created even if  the file with same name exists. That is not particularly working in my code.

Comment: @Paul as I understand it - because we are using `shutil.move(path, path)` its is raising FileExistError. I encounter this error if I run the program twice. Though the question dose not include this problem, now or latter it has to be addressed.

Comment: @sangharsh so you actually want to allow the program to just ignore existing folders? That's fairly easy, just add `exist_ok=True` as a kwarg. I still don't quite get what the problem in your code is though. For me the program simply raises an exception, as specified in the documentation.

Comment: @Paul sorry for not being clear enough. I don't want the program to ignore existing Directories (folders). I want it to ignore existing file names while creating folders.

Comment: use `os.path.exists(path)` and `os.path.isfile(path)` to test if file exist.

Comment: Also your exception handling doesn't seem right to me. If any of `makedirs` calls fail you just skip remaining calls and continue execution. You'd better loop over a list of paths and handle exception for each `makedirs` call inside `for` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a file and a folder with the same name on the same directory. The operating system does not permit it, so it is impossible for Python as well.

Comment: Before reading this answer, I was not aware about the fact that a folder and file with same name can not be created in same directory! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a file and a directory both with the same name. So you have to rename or move the file before you create the directory.

Comment: noted with thanks! I will wait for a day for others to answer before marking this answer as accepted.